# How can I embed a Kibana dashboard as an iframe in an HTML page?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, embed, opensearch-dashboards

I want to embed my dashboards made in Kibana in a webpage. There is any way I can auto-sign-in users to see Kibana dashboards in the webpage? then get this issue Refuse to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-P5polb1UreUSOe5V/Pv7tc+yeZuJXiOi/3fqhGsU7BE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I want to embed a  kibana dashboard into the web

Answer (score 0):

To embed Kibana dashboards in a webpage, you should use the Embeddable feature provided by Kibana. This feature generates a shareable URL for your dashboard that doesn't rely on inline scripts.

- In Kibana, open the dashboard you want to embed.
- Click the "Share" button.
- Generate a shareable URL for your dashboard.
- In your webpage's HTML, use an  element to embed the dashboard by setting its src attribute to the generated URL:
  `<iframe src="YOUR_GENERATED_DASHBOARD_URL" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>`

You should be able to embed your Kibana dashboard in your webpage without encountering CSP issues.

Comment: Doing same thing when it showing login page also when i am entring a login id and password then it gain reload to same login page

Comment: I am running Kibana 7.8.1 on windows. I am trying to share kibana dashboard to external web app by embedding the iframe